# Как скрыть stackLabels для сплайна в Highchart js?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Как скрыть вывод суммы для сплайна в текущем примере?:

```js
    Highcharts.chart("container", {
      title: {
            text: '$name'
        },
         tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b>'
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3', 'item 4', 'item 5']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            stackLabels: {
                    type:'column',
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                }
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
          series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
          }
        },
        series: [{
          type: 'column',
          name: 'Item 1 of stacked bar charts',
          data: [3, 2, 1, 3, 4]
        }, {
          type: 'column',
          name: 'Item 2 of stacked bar charts',
          data: [2, 3, 5, 7, 6]
        }, {
          type: 'column',
          name: 'Item 3 of stacked bar charts',
          data: [4, 3, 3, 9, 2]
        }, {
          type: 'spline',
          name:"Revenue",
          data: [15, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        }],
        
    });
```

Comment: Ошиблись языком.

Comment: нужно скрыть stackLabels для сплайна